# Flagging or auto-correcting self-referential 'let' expressions

Tags: let-binding

How do *you* catch the lisp programmer's error:

> "I typed `let`, but I really meant `let*` and wasted five to ten seconds for the **nth** time today!"

I make this mistake all the time.  Usually in a hurry or not anticipating the dependence of symbols I'm declaring I'll write:

```
(let ((foo-bar 42)
      (baz-bat (* foo-bar 2))
  (message "I bet you forgot something!"))
```

Resulting in the irritation in realizing that I miskeyed `let*` *yet again*.

```
Lisp error: (void-variable foo-bar)
```

Comment: https://github.com/Fuco1/letcheck

Comment: That "irritating error" is exactly what helps you understand your mistake, no? Just what is your question? Is it how to *prevent* your making such a mistake?

Comment: @Drew I was imprecise.  My point is not a complaint of the error; the error itself is accurate and perfectly fine.  The irritation is *my* frequent and fundamentally basic user error of misusing `let` in this particular fashion.  I am interested in anything that serves to alert me to the fact or correct the issue before I `eval-defun` / test the code.  Whether the solution is flycheck-style warnings, an autocorrect behavior, a personal policy of exclusively using `let*`, or something else-- I'm open to input.  @wasamasa hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware of [letcheck](https://github.com/Fuco1/letcheck) for this, but would prefer to have that kind of linting integrated into one of the tools Flycheck is using, ideally the byte-compiler itself.  While one may argue that an unbound variable in a `let` that suspiciously looks like one of the *previous* bindings could still be resolved from outer scope, I severely doubt this will ever practically matter.  Have you considered handing in a bug for this?

Personally, I just have it ingrained to return to the head of the let expression if I reuse a previous binding and correct it to `let*`.